# Question tag for "many a ..."

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, question-tags

Consider the sentence "Many a rose bloomed in the garden."

If you had to substitute "many a rose" with a pronoun, what would it be?

"Many a ..." takes a singular verb. Does that mean it can be substituted by the singular pronoun *it*?

If you had to add a question tag to "Many a rose bloomed in the garden", what would it be? Is "Many a rose bloomed in the garden, didn't it?" grammatical?

Comment: They (roses) bloomed in the garden.

Comment: It means many.. can not be substituted by a singular pronoun.

Comment: I would say it means `each of many`, not just `many`, that's why the verb is put in singular form, and perhaps using `it` would be more appropriate than `they`.

Comment: Here's a case where a singular verb goes with a plural question tag. You cannot say *"each of the men was wearing a hat, wasn't he"*, can you? That sounds totally wrong to me. I think if you want a question tag, you need to use *"weren't they"*.

Comment: Your example context *(many a rose grew in the garden)* sounds decidedly unnatural to me. Usually when we use this dated/poetic form, *many an X* means ***a large subset of all X's***. When there's not even an implicit reference to *other* X's, it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PeterShor, *"Each of the men was wearing a hat, wasn't he?"* is definitely wrong. Do you think the same reasoning applies to *"Many a rose bloomed in the garden"*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I know it sounds unnatural. The sentence is from a test and our tests are well-known for ridiculously unnatural sentences. I'm not even sure if they know that their sentences are unnatural. Let's take a more 'natural' sentence then: *"Many a flower is born to blush unseen."* If you *had* to add a question tag to it (not that you'd ever need to), what would it be?

Comment: @mursalin: taking a more natural example, *"many a man has been hanged on less evidence, hasn't he?"* sounds totally wrong. But  *"many a man has been hanged on less evidence, haven't they?"* sounds nearly as bad. So I don't know whether any tag works on questions like these.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I think part of the reason your second version doesn't sound quite right is because ***many a man*** is something of a "frozen form" with strong archaic/poetic/formal overtones, which clashes with modern colloquial ***haven't they?***. If you stick with those overtones and use ***have they not?*** it seems reasonable (if "affected") to me.

Comment: @mursalin: Noting the above, probably the best you could do would be *"Many a flower is born to blush unseen, **are they not?**"*. But whoever sets your tests is in the wrong job. What's the point of trying to teach non-native speakers how best to phrase something that native speakers would simply avoid in the first place?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: you're right; *"have they not"* sounds much better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks! The official solution had *"Many a rose bloomed in the garden, didn't it?"* and that sounded so wrong that I had to make sure if there was a weird grammar rule I wasn't aware of. The saddest part is, that is not the most ridiculous sentence I've been asked to add a question tag to in a test. Once they asked us to add a question tag to *"Congratulations!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I once applied to be an English teacher in Japan and they asked us to correct or verify accuracy of several very uncomfortable sentences. Unless it's my intent, I usually avoid such uncomfortable sentence structures because they make it harder for someone to understand me.

Comment: I'd almost always mark "Many a rose bloomed in the garden, didn't it?" wrong for the same reason I'd mark 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' wrong. Grammatical, but pseudo-English. For the reason @FumbleFingers gives.

Comment: @Edwin: Over the past decade or two in the UK, increasing numbers of young speakers just use ***innit*** in all "question tag" contexts. *And* in many contexts where it's not even that - just a generic "discourse marker" (which used to grate on me, but I've eventually got used to it). But *those* speakers wouldn't be likely to ever use the frozen form ***many a** [mickle makes a muckle]*.

Comment: @FF 'There's many a slip 'twixt cup and lip, innit?' is said all the time round where I live.

Comment: Tags go with verbs, not nouns. **Many roses bloomed in the garden, didn't they**? **Tags would not have been used with "many a rose", an archaic form**.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) says about the idiom "many a":

> **many a.** This idiom requires a singular verb {*many a new father has fretted about whether he is helping enough to care for the newborn*}. Essentially, because the idiom is distributive rather than aggregate in sense, the verb is singular.

The complication in the OP's example is that the verb's number is buried in a simple past tense verb (*bloomed*) that applies equally to singular and plural subjects; and this in turn encourages writers to think that perhaps the subject in "Many a rose" isn't *rose* (singular) but *Many* (plural).

This line of thinking would be less likely to occur if the example used a verb form that exposed the number of the relevant verb. Here, if the choice were between "Many a rose has bloomed..." and "Many a rose have bloomed..." I think that most native English speakers familiar with the "many a" idiom would immediately choose the version with the singular verb:

> Many a rose has bloomed in the garden.

But once you've taken that step, it hardly makes sense to adopt the plural pronoun *they* when referring to the subject. The mixed form sounds very odd:

> Many a rose has bloomed in the garden, haven't they?

whereas the consistently singular form sounds normal:

> Many a rose has bloomed in the garden, hasn't it?

Returning to the original example, with its two number-neutral verbs *bloomed* and *didn't*, I would apply the same reasoning as in the "has/have bloomed" instance, which logically yields this result:

> Many a rose bloomed in the garden, didn't it?

The noun that completes the "many a" idiom can be anything countable—*rose*, *man*, *one*, etc.—but it is always singular; and in my view, it is the true subject of the idiomatic form.

Comment: I wouldn't sat that a question tag is suitable after a 'Many a ...' pronouncement.

Comment: Garner accepts _one **couple is** having a sexual ‘dry spell’ in **their** marriage_

Comment: I don't think tags would have been used with "many a" like this. And why add to the confusion with a present perfect.

Comment: As a student of English language i would like to strongly oppose to the thought that 'many a+singular noun' this subject used in sentence can not be in plural sense in tag. Example: Many a rose is born to blush unseen aren’t they?
First of all, it is not an indefinite pronoun(single:one,each,any;compound:anyone,someone,). That's why, we should avoid this plural pronoun.
On the other hand,it sounds odd in comparison to singular pronoun ( is't it).
Besides,language is not a puzzle. Rather,it is the subject of studying ,researching,understanding and feeling. I definitely agree with Bryan Garner.

Answer (score -1):

A good question.
In my opinion, the question tag for *Many a rose bloomed in the garden*should be **didn't it**.